# Is there a nicer way to do this?

Tags: ios, swift, coding-style

This is an extremely simple piece of code, but I feel like there is a more elegant way to do this:

```
    if timeOfLastUpdate == nil {
        timeOfLastUpdate = currentTime
        return
    }

    //"Infinitesimal" moment of time used to update the position of the orbiter
    let dt:CFTimeInterval = currentTime - timeOfLastUpdate!
    timeOfLastUpdate = currentTime

    //Other code
```

I feel like there should be a more elegant way to do the following using optional chaining maybe. I don't like the fact that

a) I'm checking if the value is equal to nil instead of using some kind of optional chaining

b) The line `timeOfLastUpdate = currentTime` is repeated twice.

Is there a better way to do this? Something more in line with Swift?

Comment: Is there a reason timeOfLastUpdate starts as nil? If you could remove the necessity for the nil check, you wouldn't need to do either of the things you consider inelegant. Right now, the first time this code is called, you are skipping having a delta time by just setting timeOfLastUpdate, but shouldn't there be a delta time? The delta time between when your orbiter starts and when this is first called?

Comment: @WillM. Well, timeOfLastUpdate is supposed to represent the time since the last time the "update" function was called. If this is the first time it's being called, "timeOfLastUpdate" would be undefined wouldn't it? Hence, the nill. If your saying that delta time should be the difference between when the orbiter is added to the scene and the first "update", I can't really do that because the orbiter is added to the scene by the SKS editor, not through my code.

Comment: Don't you want the first call to the update function to do something though? Like make the first update, based on what has happened between the beginning of progress and the first call to update. Right now, you are just dropping that time like it never even happened.

Comment: @WillM. What do you mean by "between the beginning of progress and the first call to update"? Isn't the call to update the beginning of progress? It's the first thing that's called for every frame, no?

Comment: Beginning of progress was probably a bad choice of words. I cant see all of your code, but something must trigger the update loop, correct? That is what I meant. Say you start your update loop at t = 0, then the first call to update happens at t=1, as it stands right now, you just set lastUpdatedTime to 1 and return, ignoring the time between t=0 and t=1.

Comment: @WillM. Oh I see. Well, it's not me who makes the call to "update", it's done by internal code in SpriteKit. I would prefer to not modify the code that calls update since it's done by Apple's code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if timeOfLastUpdate = timeOfLastUpdate
{
  dt = currentTime - timeOfLastUpdate
}

timeOfLastUpdate = currentTime
```

If you need the code to return without running your "other code" in the case where "timeOfLastUpdate is nil, you might need to have your `timeOfLastUpdate = currentTime` assignment appear twice:

```
if timeOfLastUpdate = timeOfLastUpdate
{
  dt = currentTime - timeOfLastUpdate
  timeOfLastUpdate = currentTime
  return
}
else
{
  timeOfLastUpdate = currentTime
}

//other code here.
```

Comment: I am afraid this is not equivalent. Notice the return statement is his code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if let _timeOfLastUpdate = timeOfLastUpdate, let dt = currentTime - _timeOfLastUpdate {
    //other codes
}

//if this line of code can be placed after "//other codes", cause I see it must be placed before //other codes
timeOfLastUpdate = currentTime
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the "other code" is quite length, so I don't want to put it in an if statement.

Comment: You can put //other codes in a function then just call this function in this place.